# Subscribe returns undefined variable

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, subscribe

So in general, the shopping cart details are stored in local storage, being parsed back and assinged to an array, and then should be subscribed and posted to MongoDB, but returns "undefined":

checkout.ts

```js
confirmOrder(){
    let orderDetails: any = {};
    orderDetails.firstName = this.checkOutForm.controls['firstName'].value;
    orderDetails.lastName = this.checkOutForm.controls['lastName'].value;
    orderDetails.phone = this.checkOutForm.controls['phone'].value;
    orderDetails.address = this.checkOutForm.controls['address'].value;
    orderDetails.country = this.checkOutForm.controls['country'].value;
    orderDetails.city = this.checkOutForm.controls['city'].value;

    this.orderItem=[];
    for (let i in this.productAddedToCart) {
      this.orderItem.push({

        product_Name:this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Name,
        id:this.productAddedToCart[i].id,
        product_Price:this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Price,
        product_Quantity:this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Price,
        type:this.productAddedToCart[i].type,
        product_Img: this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Img,
        product_Description:this.productAddedToCart[i].product_Description,
       _id:this.productAddedToCart[i]._id
  
      });
   }
    orderDetails.product= this.orderItem
    debugger
    console.log("orderDetails:", orderDetails.product)

    this.connectionService.sendReceipt(this.checkOutForm.value).subscribe((res) =>{
      debugger
      console.log("res is:", res);
    });
  
    this.orderService.CreateOrder(orderDetails).subscribe((data:OrderDetails) => {
      debugger
      console.log("data is:", data) // prints nothing
      debugger
      this.globalResponse = data 
      console.log("data is:", this.globalResponse) //prints nothing
 
      debugger
    });
      alert('Your order has been received.');
      this.checkOutForm.reset();
      this.disabledSubmitButton = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      localStorage.removeItem('product');
      localStorage.removeItem('cartItemCount');

    };
```

[image]

[image]
this.globalResonse is "undefined".
Why is it not possible to console.log(data)? 
Doesnt it get subscribed?

order.service.ts:

```js
  CreateOrder(orderDetails:OrderDetails){
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/order`, orderDetails,{
    observe:'body'})
  }
```

My backend if needed(works):

```js
//create order
orderRoute.route('/').post((req, res) =>{
    Product.findById(req.body.productId)
    .populate('product')
    .then(product => {
        if(!product){
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: "product not found"
            });
        }
        const order = new OrderDetails({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            product: req.body.productId,
            email: req.body.email,
            firstName:req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            address: req.body.address,
        });
        return order.save()
        })
        
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            
            return res.status(200).json({
                
                message: "Order was Created",
                
                order: {
                    order_id: result._id,
                    product: result.product,
                    firstName:result.firstName,
                    lastName: result.lastName,
                    email: result.email,
                    phone: result.phone,
                    address: result.address,
                    createdAt: new Date,
                },
                request:{
                    type:"GET",
                    order_url: "http://localhost:5000/order/" + result._id
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error:err
            });
        });
    
    });
```

I also receive 2 errors:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

(node:17548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for not to receive any data from executing `CreateOrder()` because it get an interesting **HTTP** error. From following this [document](https://www.codementor.io/@oparaprosper79/understanding-node-error-err_http_headers_sent-117mpk82z8) I got this content and it says,

***Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] is an interesting error that is fired up when a server tries to send more than one response to a client. What this means is that for a given client request the server previously sent a response (either a success response with the resource requested or error response for a bad request) back to the client and now is unexpectedly trying to send another response***

So your backend tries to send the response twice. that's the issue here. If you could open the network tab in the browser console you can inspect if it's true.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,  the response from the header is : {message: "product not found"}
message: "product not found", which is the error in my backend, but the whole product information is shown on "Request Payload", and also in the header I created for testing..product-token: [{"_id":"5e5a6307d07a33280ce8c49c","product_Name":"GEL-Contend 5","product_Description":"Shoes 2","product_Price":85,"product_Img":"../assets/shoes/asics-mens-gel-contend-5-running-shoes.JPG","id":13,"product_Quantity":1,"type":"shoes"}]
Referer: http://localhost:4200/checkout